# Clear tint on a vector drawable programmatically?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to toggle the tint of an `ImageView` whose source is a vector drawable:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_lightbulb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lightbulb" />
```

Looking at other solutions on this site I tried this on an imageview in my recyclerview adapter:

```
lightbulbIV.setOnClickListener {
                // read tint of vector drawable, unfilled by default or yellow
                val currentColor =
                    ImageViewCompat.getImageTintList(lightbulbIV)?.defaultColor
                if (currentColor == null) {
                    // make vector drawable yellow
                    ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(
                        lightbulbIV,
                        ColorStateList.valueOf(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(parent.context, R.color.yellow)
                        )
                    )
                } else
                    // unfill the vector drawable 
                    ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(lightBulbIV, null)
```

`setImageTintList` with null just removes the image altogether, which is not what I want `lightBulbIV.clearColorFilter()` also does not produce the desired effect.  What do I need to do to clear the tint so that next time the image is clicked it is set to the tint?

Answer (score -1):

this one worked for me. Could you please try this code.

```
    logo.setOnClickListener {
        // read tint of vector drawable, unfilled by default or yellow
        val currentColor =
            ImageViewCompat.getImageTintList(logo)?.defaultColor
        if (currentColor == null) {
            // make vector drawable yellow
            ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(
                logo,
                ColorStateList.valueOf(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.purple_200)
                )
            )
        } else
        // unfill the vector drawable
            ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(logo, null)
    }
```

Comment: so that is identical to my original posted snippet except your imageview is called logo instead of lightbulbIV.  Can you post your vector drawable xml?

Comment: Not identical to your code. I have used  ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.yellow) instead of ContextCompat.getColor(parent.context, R.color.yellow)